# How to assert that a pandas data frame filtered on a condition is true

Tags: python, pandas, pytest

So I have a pytest testing the results of a query that returns pandas dataframe.

I want to assert that a particular column `col` has all the values that are a substring of a given input.

So this below gives me the rows (dataframe) that have that column's `col` value containing some input part. How can I assert it to be true?

```
assert result_df[result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category)].bool == True
```

doesn't work

Comment: Are you attempting to assert that all values in the filtered dataframe are True?

Comment: @Kapocsi Yes, I am attempting for all to be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. `assert result_df[result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category)].bool` works

or `assert result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all` (Thanks to @jezrael for suggesting all)

Comment: Problem of code is if check `print ((result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all))` it return `bound method Series.all ` and if use `assert` it working like `print (bool(result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all))` - always it return `True`

Comment: Also for `print ((result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).bool))` it return `<bound method NDFrame.bool` and then always True

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need [`Series.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) for check if all values of filtered `Series` are `True`s:

```
assert result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all()
```

**Sample**:

```
result_df = pd.DataFrame({
         'col':list('aaabbb')
})

print (result_df)
  col
0   a
1   a
2   a
3   b
4   b
5   b
```

---

```
category = 'b'
assert result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all()
```

> AssertionError

**Detail**:

```
print (result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category))
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: col, dtype: bool

print (result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all())
False
```

---

```
category = 'a|b'
assert result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all()

print (result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category))

0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
Name: col, dtype: bool

print (result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all())
True
```

Comment: Using your code, I get error `KeyError: u'the label [bool] is not in the [columns]'`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I Think `all` will be without parentheses as then only it works.

Comment: @jezreal This is the correct syntax when I ran: `assert result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all`

Comment: @Atihska - I think not, because if use my sample data and `category = 'b'
assert result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category).all` it not raise `AssertionError`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
assert result_df[result_df['col'].astype(str).str.contains(category)].bool.all(axis=None) == True
```

Please refer to the pandas docs for more info:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html

The reason your code doesn't work is because you are trying to test whether the dataframe object is True, not all of the values in it.